# My pixels aren't displayed correcly in a button in Outlook desktop for an email html?

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, email-templates

I am trying to create a buttoon centered vertically in Outlook, I am using a code that another developer worked on, and trying to re-adapt it

in the code I am trying to set fixed values to avoid any issues but in outlook it displays extra space

in Outlook web, mobile, Gmail, browsers, etc, this is good and expected  :

[image]

in Outloook Desktop :

[image]

This is the logic I am setting witgh my html code :

[image]

Border with 1 px and two spacers rows with 8px, and text container with line-height: 18px; ..

This is my HTML

```
<tr>
    <td valign="middle" style="padding: 0px; vertical-align: middle;height:35px;" align="center" height="35">
        <table
            style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;height:35px;"
            cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="35">

            <tr>
                <td valign="middle" border="1" class="borders" dir="ltr"
                    style="padding: 0px; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #4E4E4E; border-image: none; width: 220px; height: 34px; text-align: center; color: #4B4B4B; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #EBEBEB;"
                    bgcolor="#303335" align="center" height="34">
                    <table
                        style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;"
                        cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td dir="ltr"
                                style="padding: 0px; border-image: none; width: 220px; height: 8px; text-align: center; color: #4B4B4B; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none;  background-color: #ffffff;vertical-align: middle;"
                                valign="middle" height="8" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td dir="ltr"
                                style="padding: 0px; border-image: none; width: 220px;  text-align: center; color: #4B4B4B; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; line-height: 18px; font-size: 15px; background-color: #EBEBEB;vertical-align: middle;"
                                valign="middle" bgcolor="#303335" align="center">
                                <a href="%%=RedirectTo(CONCAT( TreatAsContent(@contentblock_link), '&amp;utm_clickposition=cta', TreatAsContent(@contentblock_link_anchor)))=%%"
                                    style="color: #4B4B4B ; text-transform: uppercase; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 18px; letter-spacing: 0.5px; font-family: &quot;HelveticaNeueLight&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; ">%%=Field(@campaign_input_data,
                                    concat(@contentblock, '_cta'))=%%</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td dir="ltr"
                                style="padding: 0px; border-image: none; width: 220px; height: 8px; text-align: center; color: #4B4B4B; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none;  background-color: #ffffff;vertical-align: middle;"
                                valign="middle" height="8" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Use `&zwnj;` in the blank `td`'s

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your third row is expanding. I believe what is happening is Outlook is inserting a blank paragraph - though why that is not happening in the first row too is a mystery.

To ensure the right height for a blank row (in between the `<td>'s`), use the following construction:

`<p style="margin:0;padding:0;font-size:8px;line-height:8px;">&nbsp;</p>`

Also ensure there are no spaces in between the `<td>'s`. I would use that on both the top and bottom row, for consistency. (Once you do this, you don't need the `height: 8px;` in the `<td>` style.)